# Solr 5.3 my core's /update url not found

Tags: python, django, solr, pysolr

I create a core in solr 5.3 using haystack for my django application and try to do `python manage.py rebuild_index`, it just gives this error message. The part `/update/?commit=true` looks strange for me. I try to manually change it to `/update?commit=true`, but still does not work. In browser, it just says 404. Anyone has any idea on it? Thanks!

> Failed to clear Solr index: Failed to connect to server at
>   'http://localhost:8983/solr/#/my_core/update/?commit=true', are you
>   sure that URL is correct? Checking it in a browser might help:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8983): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /solr/ (Caused by : [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused)

Answer (score 0):

Any part after a `#` in a standard HTTP URL is an anchor, and meant for consumtion on the client. Therefor it's never being transmitted to the server, which means that you end up making a request to `http://localhost:8983/solr/` - which probably isn't the URL you want to query.

Just `http://localhost:8983/solr/my_core/update?commit=true` should work.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh! I think I figured out what happened. Since I work on a Docker container, the ip should be the Docker container's ip not localhost. Just changed the localhost to Docker's ip, and it works fine now. Thanks!